# How high does Lifeinvader stock go?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I've read several "guides" for *GTA V* singleplayer that say you can make a lot of money from buying Lifeinvader stock when it crashes after the Lifeinvader mission and that it will eventually go up.  They all say the stock will drop to around $3/share and that it won't start to go back up until after you complete the main storyline.

I have completed the main storyline in my game, the stock went to around $2.90/share, and several days have gone by since the end of the storyline. The stock in my game is staying around $3.50/share.  I've tried saving back to back repeatedly to advance several days and it doesn't seem to be going up at any noticeable pace. Will it go higher than that and if so what is a good price to sell at?